# Chinese characters to equivalent html on python

Tags: python, django, decoding, cjk

I am working on a Japanese project on Django. I have most of characters on its html code equivalent to avoid them to display unproperly. For insance, instead of "死", I use "`&#27515;`". However, I hace a csv with info I need to compare to other data on the project, but its characters are not in html code.

Is there a way to decode those chinese characters into html code to have the code comparing some entries?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

Should do the trick.

Copy pasting should work as well, or using pinyin. Try this:

```
<p>你好<p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this tool might work for you? Converts plain kanji into unicode, which I think is what you are looking for. http://www.pinyin.info/tools/converter/chars2uninumbers.html

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.